# NoSuchMethodError when running Checkstyle 5.5 in Play 2.2 project?

Tags: sbt, checkstyle, playframework-2.2, nosuchmethoderror

I previously had Checkstyle implemented as an sbt task in Play 2.1. As of Play 2.2, I get the following error:

```
[error] (*:checkstyle) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.of([Ljava/lang/Comparable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet;
```

A simple Play project illustrating this problem in detail is available [here](https://github.com/philipmjohnson/play-checkstyle-problem).

Can anyone provide insight into how to fix this problem?

Comment: This is [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/bugs/690/), which was closed, I believe erroneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as Robin Green notes, is due an unfixed bug in the implementation of the JavadocStyleCheck.  Removing that check from the configuration XML file fixes the problem.